# Insert into table with multiple values in subquery

Tags: sql, insert

```
INSERT INTO Reference_TB] ([RequestID] ,[WaveID]) 
VALUES (2222,(select tWaveID from @Table2))
```

I am using above query to insert into table. I know `@Table2` has multiple `tWaveID` and that's why it is showing error :

> *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

How to resolve that and insert `twaveID` repeating `RequestID` as `2222` for all entries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) statement instead of a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO Reference_TB] ([RequestID] ,[WaveID]) 
(select 2222, tWaveID from @Table2)
```

Comment: Great one! This did exactly what I wanted. However, in SQL Server, I get syntax error if I put the `columnName FROM Table` part at the head of the `SELECT` list. It has to be at the end. Do you know why that is?

Answer (score 4):

Unsure of exact syntax as you didnt specify a system.

use a Insert select will insert all values

```
INSERT INTO Reference_TB] ([RequestID] ,[WaveID])
select 2222,tWaveID from @Table2
```