# Insert multiple rows from other table - "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I table 1 contains:

```
    |col1|
    | 1  |
    | 2  |
    | 1  |
    | 3  |
    | 1  |
    | 2  |
    | 4  |
    | 2  |
    | 3  |
    | 1  |
```

and I have another table has a column name `val`, and my code is

```
INSERT INTO table2(value) VALUES ((select distinct col1 from table1))
```

I got the #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.
How can I get multiple rows insert into my table2 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert into table with multiple values in subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532162/insert-into-table-with-multiple-values-in-subquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `values` statement when using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO table2(value)
    select distinct col1
    from table1;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO table2(value)
select distinct col1 
from table1
```